# Webpack-dev-server throws an error on Windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I need your help, I have a react project in https://github.com/ReuvenLiran/Netomedia . 
It works great on Linux, but on Windows it throws an error:

> Nettomdeia@0.4.3 start C:\Users\user1\Documents\Dev\Netomedia
>   better-npm-run dev-server

```
running better-npm-run in C:\Users\user1\Documents\Dev\Netomedia
Executing script: dev-server

to be executed: ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --config build/webpack.config.js
net.js:641
    throw new TypeError('invalid data');
    ^

TypeError: invalid data
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:641:11)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user1\Documents\Dev\Netomedia\node_modules\better-npm-run\lib\exec.js:32:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! Nettomdeia@0.4.3 start: `better-npm-run dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Nettomdeia@0.4.3 start script 'better-npm-run dev-server'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the Nettomdeia package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     better-npm-run dev-server
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs Nettomdeia
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls Nettomdeia
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

What is the problem and how do I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly related issue? Although it looks to have been closed already. https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/947

Comment: Thanks, I tried to upgrade better-npm-run, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it. I updated better-npm-run to latest version and my scripts  used to be './node_module/.bin/webpack-dev-server' instead of 'webpack-dev-server'. Windows uses path variables.